# Using DateTime::diff() to return days between two dates

Tags: php

I am currently using DateTime::diff() to return the days, hours, minutes, and seconds between two dates.

The problem is when the differences is more than 30 days, instead of returning 33 days it returns 1 month and 3 days.

Is there a way to tell it to return days and not month accordingly.

Some code:

```
$date1      =   new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
$date2      =   new DateTime($row['start']);

$interval   =   $date1->diff($date2);

$days       =   $newInfo[$key]['days'] = $interval->format("%d"); 
$hours      =   $newInfo[$key]['hours'] = $interval->format("%h"); 
$minutes    =   $newInfo[$key]['minutes'] = $interval->format("%i"); 
$seconds    =   $newInfo[$key]['seconds'] = $interval->format("%s");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a special format parameter for this exact case:

```
<?php
$days = $newInfo[$key]['days'] = $interval->format("%a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd want to use [DateInterval::format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

From the example section:

```
$january = new DateTime('2010-01-01');
$february = new DateTime('2010-02-01');
$interval = $february->diff($january);

// %a will output the total number of days.
echo $interval->format('%a total days')."\n";
```