# How do I stop DateTime and date_diff refreshing at 30/31 days

Tags: php, datetime

I am having an issue with the below code I need it to count past 30/31 days but when it reaches a count of 31 days it goes back to 1

```
      $startDate = new DateTime();
      $endDate = new DateTime($row['vadded']);
      $diff = date_diff($endDate,$startDate);
```

and this is the output

```
      <td><?php echo $diff->format('%d days')?></td>
```

Comment: %d is only the diff in the numeric value for days. use %a to get "Total number of days as a result of a DateTime::diff() or (unknown) otherwise" https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Your a star thank you

Comment: @JimL You should have posted that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DateTime::diff() to return days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282842/using-datetimediff-to-return-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: @Dharman I assumed it was a duplicate but didn't have time looking it up so just threw in a comment to help OP as I know how painful it can be to sit with a rather basic issue that just wont work. I've flagged this question now :)